# R: invalid use of XX < 0 in 'X11_MetricInfo'

Tags: r, plot, x11

I compiled R 4.1.0 from source code on my Fedora 34 Worstation.

Now when I try to plot something on screen, the following error appears:

```
> plot(s)
Hit <Return> to see next plot: 
Error in title(...) : invalid use of -961 < 0 in 'X11_MetricInfo'
```

How to solve it?