# Is there a Wayland backend for R?

Tags: r, x11, wayland

I compiled R 4.1.0 from source on my Fedora 34 Workstation.

I had to install the X11 libraries to do so.

Is there a way to enable Wayland, so that it renders on Wayland directly?

I am also having problems with X11, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68071628/r-invalid-use-of-xx-0-in-x11-metricinfo).

Comment: have you considered using r-core 4.1 from Rawhide? https://fedora.pkgs.org/rawhide/fedora-aarch64/R-core-4.1.0-1.fc35.aarch64.rpm.html (i'm afraid it's still x11, but perhaps it will work)